# Use scanf() for first letter

Tags: objective-c, scanf

I have somewhat of a command line where the user types in 1 letter, and when the user types in more than 1 letter, the program takes the first letter typed. How do I go about doing this, as  what I'm doing doesn't seem to work out for me:

```
    char ans, *d;

    Sequence *seq = [[Sequence alloc] init];

    while (k < 10) {
        k++;
        [seq generate];
        printf("%i. %s\n\n>>> ", k, [seq.full cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
        scanf("%c%s", &ans, &d);

        NSString *input = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", ans];
        if (input == seq.answer) {
            correct ++;
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I just want to clarify that the 'd' variable is used as a dummy, so that the Enter key doesn't get registered.

Comment: if you want to get only the first letter means how about using  `getch()`;

Comment: `getch()` is in `conio.h`, which I don't have because I'm on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked in **< curses.h>** to see what the **getch()** function does?
Please Refer: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/curses.h.html
Its for Mac...